# Scala template not able to json

Tags: json, scala, playframework

I am using scala template with playframework. I am tring to read a value from json but I am getting JSError

> JsError(List((/"active\"onshore"\"sunnyvale",List(ValidationError(error.path.missing,WrappedArray())))))

Here is my JsonString

```
rfrdetails = {
    "active": {
        "onshore": {
            "sunnyvale": 10,
            "cupertino": 20,
            "sfo": 8
        }
    }
}
```

My template.scala.html

```
@(rfrdetails : String)

@import play.api.libs.json._
@rfrjsonex(label:String) = @{
    println(label)
    var json: JsValue = Json.parse(rfrdetails)
    ((__ \ label).read[Int]).reads(json)
}
```

calling the above reuseable code as below.

```
<tr>
<td>@rfrjsonex("\"active" + "\\" + "\"onshore\"" + "\\" + "\"sunnyvale\"")</td>
</tr>
```

The reusable code works fine when I give the json path in code block

```
@rfrjsonex(label:String) = @{
    println(label)
    var json: JsValue = Json.parse(rfrdetails)
    ((__ \ "active"\"onshore"\"sunnyvale").read[Int]).reads(json)
}
```

Where am'I going wrong. Not sure if its very silly. From the error, I can see in the JsError there is "/" before "active" , not sure how its getting appended. JsError(List((/"active\"onshore"\"sunnyvale"

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well formatted question for a first time poster

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The \ symbol is not a literal. It's a method used with Scala's infix notation system.

```
__ \ "a" \ "b"
```

is syntactic sugar for

```
(JsPath.\("a")).\("b")
```

So trying to package the path as a String and then pass it in as a parameter makes no sense.  You can only pass in the String parameters to *each* method, but you will need to know exactly how many levels you're trying to go into the JsValue structure ahead of time.

Comment: I am now passing the JsPath itself as parameter. `<td>@rfrjsonex((JsPath.\ ("active")).\("onshore") \ ("sunnyvale"))</td>`